# expect command is not passing env variable in ubuntu focal

Tags: linux, bash, perl, expect, ubuntu-20.04

I'm using `expect` (v5.45.4-2build1) to automate generation of client certs using easy-rsa in ubuntu focal.
As per easy-rsa, to customize cert validity we need to pass `EASYRSA_CERT_EXPIRE` variable.
But for some reason, my expect script is not able to fetch this variable.
Here's the code for script.exp:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1
#exp_internal 1

set MY_PASSPHRASE [lindex $argv 0];
set USERNAME [lindex $argv 1];
set ttl [lindex $argv 2];

send "export EASYRSA_CERT_EXPIRE=$ttl\r"
spawn /bin/bash

set MSG "Executing script.exp for $USERNAME and $ttl";
send "echo 'INFO $MSG'>> /var/log/app/my_app.log\r"

send "cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa\r"

send "export EASYRSA_CERT_EXPIRE=$ttl\r"

send "./easyrsa gen-req $USERNAME\r"
expect "*Enter PEM pass phrase:"
send -- "$MY_PASSPHRASE\r"
expect "*Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:"
send -- "$MY_PASSPHRASE\r"
expect "*Common Name *$USERNAME*"
send -- "\r"
expect "*Keypair and certificate request completed*"
send -- "\r"
exit 0
```

Strangely, this works fine if i run the script via `expect script.exp`.
But I want to use this in my perl script and it is not working from the perl script.

This is how I'm calling my expect script:

```
my $cmd_out_csr = system("expect script.exp $my_passphrase $username $ttl");
```

Just running, `expect script.exp $my_passphrase $username $ttl` from cmd works fine.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What about this one - `my $cmd_out_csr = \`expect script.exp $my_passphrase $username $ttl\`;`

Comment: @vkk05 i dont want the output, just the status. the problem is expect is not considering my env variable `EASYRSA_CERT_EXPIRE ` when i'm calling it from my perl script.

Comment: Can you paste your entire expect script code. I cannot see where you're collecting the arguments. Something like `set username [lindex $argv 0]; ..`

Comment: @vkk05 updated the entire code.

Comment: Like i said, the code works when run directly from terminal but when exectuted from perl script, not able to add `EASYRSA_CERT_EXPIRE` env variable

Comment: Do any of `$my_passphrase`, `$username` or `$ttl` contain spaces, quotes or other shell-special characters?

Comment: @GhanshyamGupta: Are you able to print values of `$my_passphrase`, `$username` and `$ttl` in the expect prompt?

Comment: @vkk05 yes.
@glennjackman i have just upper/lower case, digits and `.`. Not sure if `.` is a shell-special one

Comment: show the value of `$ttl`

Comment: `my $cmd_out_csr = system('expect', 'script.exp', $my_passphrase, $username, 365);`
$ttl is 365

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. use the perl `system` command with a list of arguments:

   ```perl
   system('expect', 'script.exp', $my_passphrase, $username, $ttl);
   ```
2. when creating the variable in the remote shell, send quotes around the value:

   ```
   send "export EASYRSA_CERT_EXPIRE=\"$ttl\"\r"
   ```

These two things will protect the value of `$ttl` if it contains whitespace.

---

Another thought: expect (via Tcl) can `cd` and set environment variables. Instead of spawning a bash shell, spawn easyrsa directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1
#exp_internal 1

lassign $argv MY_PASSPHRASE USERNAME ttl

set f [open /var/log/app/my_app.log a]
puts $f "INFO Executing [info script] for $USERNAME and $ttl"
close $f

cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
set env(EASYRSA_CERT_EXPIRE) $ttl

spawn ./easyrsa gen-req $USERNAME

expect "*Enter PEM pass phrase:"
send -- "$MY_PASSPHRASE\r"
expect "*Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:"
send -- "$MY_PASSPHRASE\r"
expect "*Common Name *$USERNAME*"
send -- "\r"
expect "*Keypair and certificate request completed*"
send -- "\r"
expect eof

puts "Done."
```